# want one more option in jsp page while clicking a link

Tags: java, spring, jsp

there is 2 jap page(suppose a.jsp, b.jsp). In a.jsp there have 2 link(link.abc,link.def).
In b.jsp have 3 column.. 
Both the link points to b.jsp while clicking. but there is small business require, if you will click link.abc then it should display 3 columns in b.jsp. 
if you will click link.def then there should display 4 columns in b.jsp how it i cant get any idea.
i have tried some coding here but i m not getting proper idea for this..

enter code here
    
     0}">

```
        <td class="label">
            <form:label path="noOfQuestions">
                    <span class="requiredFieldMarker"><fmt:message key="label.requiredMarker"/></span><fmt:message key="label.noofQuestions"/><fmt:message key="label.postfix"/>
            </form:label>
        </td>
        <td class="data" >
            <form:input path="noOfQuestions" maxlength="3" size="5"/>
        </td>
    </tr>    
</c:if> 
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a crude way, you can pass number of columns you want to display on b.jsp from a.jsp link as get parameter.

Eg,

```
<a href="b.jsp?parameter=3">Link</a>
```

and Read the same in b.jsp, and make your columns 3.

----Explanation ---

Ok do this,

In your a.jsp modify link to

```
<a href="b.jsp?columnValue=3">Link</a>
```

In your b.jsp add line

```
<% String columnValue = request.getParameter("columnValue") %>
```

Now use columnValue in b.jsp to create number of columns.

Comment: no its not working its coming same 4 columns in both link @Abhishek Anand

Comment: give me some idea plz... -Abhishek Anand

Comment: getting error.. Unable to compile class for JSP -Abhishek Anand

Comment: //
i tried this in my a.jsp but still not working this..
      <urlencrypt:url value="addEQuestion.action" htmlEscape="true" var="addeQuestionLink" >
<spring:param name="<%=AppConstants.PAGE%>" value="1"/>
<spring:param name="<%=BornOnDate.BORN_ON_DATE%>" value="<%=BornOnDate.getBornOnDate(request)%>"/>
<spring:param name="tId" value="${tBean.tId}"/>       
</urlencrypt:url>
[<a href="${addeQuestionLink} parameter=3""><fmt:message key="link.add.eQuestion" /></a>]